# Getting ansible_play_hosts from previous play?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that interacts with the management card in a bunch of servers, and then produces a report based on that information. Structurally it looks like:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: do something with redfish
      uri:
         ...
      register: something

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: produce report
      template:
        ...
      loop: "{{ SOME_LIST_OF_HOSTS }}"
```

Originally, the `template` task in the second was looping over `groups.all`, but that causes a number of complications if we limited the target hosts using `-l` on the command line (like `ansible-playbook -l only_cluster_a ...`). In that case, I would like the `template` task to loop over only the hosts targeted by the first play. In other words, I want to know `ansible_play_hosts_all` from the previous play.

This is what I've come up with:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: true
      set_fact:
        saved_play_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"

    ...other tasks go here...

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          play_hosts: "{{ saved_play_hosts }}"
```

Is that the best way of doing this?

Comment: have you tested my answer?

Answer (score 2):

you could use add_host module: at the end of first play you add a task:

```
- name: add variables to dummy host
  add_host:
    name: "variable_holder"
    shared_variable:  "{{ saved_play_hosts }}"
```

and you could trap the value in second play:

```
- name: second play
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    play_hosts: "{{ hostvars['variable_holder']['shared_variable'] }}"
  tasks:
    :
    :
```

Comment: dont forget to close your question by validating your or my answer